# What can drop the session?

Tags: .net, session, iis

We have a lot of websites on one pool(nearly 100). It's bad, but we can't change it for now.

Sometimes on one of our websites session unexpectedly drops and we can't find out why.

I know, that because we have only one pool then if one of the websites has fatal error then pool could be recycled and this will drop the session for all websites. But I can't find this fatal error.

So, is there a way to log session drop/expiration event somehow? Or somehow to know exactly what has droped our session.

Comment: Have you looked in the Event Viewer or IIS Logs that may have details about what happened?

Comment: I'm interested which of the Errors in logs can drop Session(or recycle pool)?

Comment: Are the sessions of *all* sites dropped (=app pool recycle), or just of a single site? If one site, is it one particular site or any one?

Answer (score 0):

There are settings in IIS to recycle an app pool ever 1740 minutes by default that would be one configuration piece to check.

There are methods in the `Global.asax.cs` file that could be used to add logging assuming the error allows for a graceful shut down like `Application_End` as well as `Session_End`.

There can also be hardware failures that could cause issues as if a server is rebooted, then the session data is likely to be gone if it is stored in the process.